# How do I encode the FLV to a temporary file and then output that to stdout with FFMpeg?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, video, ffmpeg

I know ffmpeg supports piping.  I am trying to achieve what was described in [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1021467/since-you-cant-write-ffmpeg-to-stdout-with-flv-to-mp4-is-there-a-workaround/1021479#1021479) quoted below

> If you are willing to accept a solution that does not truly stream the
>   resulting frames, but does still adhere to your specification (read
>   FLV from URL resource, output MP4 to stdout), you can always try to
>   first encode the FLV to a temporary file and then output that to
>   stdout.

Would I be able to achive this with ffmpeg via piping with something like this?

```
ffmpeg -i "%s" -c:v libx264 -c:a copy -f mp4 temp.mp4 | -
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there. You already succeed in encoding your input file to an MP4 file named `temp.mp4`:

```
ffmpeg -i "%s" -c:v libx264 -c:a copy -f mp4 temp.mp4
```

To read the resulting file to stdout, once it's been fully written, you can use `cat`:

```
cat temp.mp4
```

To combine both, use the `&&` operator (which makes the second command only execute when the first command succeeds):

```
ffmpeg -i "%s" -c:v libx264 -c:a copy -f mp4 temp.mp4 && cat temp.mp4
```

You can then pipe the output of this command to whatever program you like.

Note that in general this pattern (e.g. reading a file with `cat` solely to pipe it into another program) is frowned upon when the other program has native support for reading the respective file. Pass `temp.mp4` as an input file to the consuming program whenever possible instead.